# Can you get the tag of a date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

I am opening different date picker fragments in my android app.

The fragement is opened like this.

```
DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MY_TAG");
```

The I implemented the **onDateSet** method which has the picked date and a DatePicker object. Now I tried to get the tag from the DatePicker object to check which picker has been shown.

There is a method `datePicker.getTag()`, but this returns **null**.

Is there a way to get the tag which has been commited in the **show method**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `datePicker.getTag()`, you are getting the wrong tag; which is the `DatePicker` tag, not the `DatePickerFragment` tag.

To see the right tag, just use `getTag()` inside your custom `DatePickerFragment`

> getTag() inside my Fragement class works fine. But how to I pass the
>   tag back to my activity where I called show() My Fragement currently
>   only contains the onCreateDialog method where I return a new
>   DatePickerDialog instance

You can pass a listener to your `DatePickerFragment` constructor, and trigger its callback with the Fragment tag whenever you set a date.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    interface OnDateAdjustedListener {
        void onDateAdjusted(String tag);
    }

    private OnDateAdjustedListener mOnDateAdjustedListener;


    // Constructor with a Listener
    public DatePickerFragment(OnDateAdjustedListener onDateAdjustedListener) {
        mOnDateAdjustedListener = onDateAdjustedListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // .... Handle onCreateDialog

    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        // .... Handle onDateSet

        // callback with fragment tag 
        mOnDateAdjustedListener.onDateAdjusted(getTag());
    }


}
```

And in your activity modify the constructor, and implement the interface

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, DatePickerFragment.OnDateAdjustedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatePickerFragment dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDateAdjusted(String tag) {
        Toast.makeText(this, tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `getTag()` inside my Fragement class works fine. But how to I pass the tag back to my activity where I called `show()`

My Fragement currently only contains the `onCreateDialog` method where I return a new DatePickerDialog instance